# Filtering level of logger messages

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I started using Log4j 2 today and I saw three ways to specify message level:
1. with filter.threshold
2. in appender itself
3. or in rootLogger
Which way is recommended to use when specifying logger's message level?

I currently have this code as Log4j2 conf file:

```
status = error
dest = err
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = logs/log.log

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = trace

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = ConsoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%t.%-15c{1}] [%p] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level = trace

appender.randomAccessFile.type = RandomAccessFile
appender.randomAccessFile.name = File
appender.randomAccessFile.filename = logs/log.log
appender.randomAccessFile.immediateFlush = false
appender.randomAccessFile.append = false
appender.randomAccessFile.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.randomAccessFile.layout.pattern = %-10[%t.%c{1}] [%p] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %m%n
appender.randomAccessFile.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.randomAccessFile.filter.threshold.level = trace

rootLogger.level = trace
rootLogger.includeLocation = false
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = ConsoleLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = File
```

As you can see I have levels in 3 places. I think those appender filters are for those specific logging inteface and rootLogger.level for global filter, but what this code do? That's the default value or what?

```
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = trace
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From log4j [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#Filters) -

> Filters may be configured in one of four locations:
>
> 1. Context-wide Filters are configured directly in the configuration.
>      Events that are rejected by these filters will not be passed to
>      loggers for further processing. Once an event has been accepted by a
>      Context-wide filter it will not be evaluated by any other Context-wide
>      Filters nor will the Logger's Level be used to filter the event. The
>      event will be evaluated by Logger and Appender Filters however.
> 2. Logger Filters are configured on a specified Logger. These are evaluated
>      after the Context-wide Filters and the Log Level for the Logger.
>      Events that are rejected by these filters will be discarded and the
>      event will not be passed to a parent Logger regardless of the
>      additivity setting.
> 3. Appender Filters are used to determine if a specific Appender should handle the formatting and publication of the event.
> 4. Appender Reference Filters are used to determine if a Logger should route the event to an appender.

In simple words, below is the filter sequence in which log messages are filtered -

1. Context-wide filters
2. Level declared at logger level
3. Appender filter

If level is becoming specific in lower sequences, log messages are filtered again. e.g. If level set at context-wide filter is `WARN` and level set at appender filter is `ERROR`, then log messages with `ERROR` log level will get logged.

If level is becoming generic in lower sequences, level set at higher sequence is used. e.g. If level set at context-wide filter is `WARN` and level set at logger level is `INFO`, then log messages with `WARN` log level will be forwarded to appender.

Now, with above explanation, you can understand that each filter sequence has its own scope of control. With a small configuration file, you may be thinking it is not very useful but it would be very useful where you have a large configuration file with multiple appenders and loggers.

So, there is no recommended configuration. Given your configuration, I would prefer to remove context-wide filters and appender filters. Instead create a `Logger` and control log level using `Logger`. `RootLogger` level is generally set to `WARN` or `ERROR` for avoiding detailed logging of application libraries.